# How to change font in a dialog box in android?

Tags: android, fonts, dialog, custom-font

I am able to change from default font to custom font in an activity,but I am unable to change in a dialog box the crashes on opening of the dialog.Any snippet or example will be greatly helpful.Thanks.

Comment: what is the error in logcat? Also post the code where you are getting error.

Comment: you should  share code of your activity with Log list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use custom Dialog, the inflating layout's textview can be altered with your needs to change font and it reflects in your dialog box.